# Auto posting TO instagram

Tags: rss, social-networking, instagram

Does anyone know of a way to auto post TO Instagram as opposed to from it? Google is useless at this, only pages on how to create auto posts from your Instagram page. The popular RSS auto-post Apps such as RSS Graffiti, Dlvr.it and Hootsuite do not seem able to.

My website updates with "reports" throughout the day. Each report has an image. Once the report is added I use the RSS Apps above to autopost to Facebook and Twitter. Seems to not be possible to do it with Instagram. I have a hard time believing so.

Anyone got any tips here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say I don't think that's possible.  From the [API documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/):

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> - Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>     from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist
>     access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
> - We want to fight
>     spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources,
>     it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All
>     this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a
>     consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

Comment: It makes sense I guess. It's just annoying

Comment: So everybody who uses a real camera is not taking pictures that are high quality enough for instagram, like, every professional photographer, every photojournalist etc. You are in contempt of photography.